# SyntaxError - "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

Each time I attempt to run my code, I keep getting this error message:

[image]

This is my code:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.  That said,  you need to have some code in those elif blocks, even if it is just a ```pass```

Comment: Are your empty `elif` clauses truly empty, or do you in fact have code there which was removed in your post?  Your error message differs from what Python gives for an empty `elif` clause.  It's possibly that some of the unshown code is inconsistently indented.  Or perhaps you have hard tabs on some lines and spaces on others, which will result in such an error.  Also, don't post images of code.  Post the actual code.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two consecutive `elif`s with nothing between them. If you want temporary placeholders, try using `pass` or `raise NotImplementedError` until you've implemented those sections.

However, the error message you should get for that issue is `IndentationError: expected an indented block`.

Perhaps you have mixed spaces and tabs?